# Regular Expression to Match Exact Character and Numbers

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I want to match a string that can be either `KH1` or `KH2` or ... `KH99`.

I did,

```
public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "KH1";
    if(name.matches("[[K][H][1-9][0-9]]") || name.matches("[[K][H][1-9]]")){
        System.out.println("VALID NAME");
    }else{
        System.out.println("INVALID NAME");
    }
 }
}
```

It doesnot work. I get `INVALID NAME`.

What is the correct way for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the outer square brackets:

```
if(name.matches("[K][H][1-9][0-9]?")){
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/MXNIiY)

The issue is that you enclosed the whole pattern into a character class with outer `[...]`, and all the symbols inside (except the brackets) were treated as single literal symbols, and the whole expression could only match 1 character.

Talking about optimizations: the alternation is not really necessary here since you can apply [`?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) to the `[0-9]` class to make it optional. `?` matches 0 or 1 occurrence of the preceding subpattern.

Also note that `[K][H]` makes sense if you plan to add more options into the character classes, otherwise you might as well use

```
if(name.matches("KH[1-9][0-9]?")){
```

or

```
if(name.matches("KH[1-9]\\d?")){
```

The `\d` is a [shorthand class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) that matches digit(s).

Comment: I hope it is quite clear now. If you still have doubt, please feel free to drop a comment. Note that by *(except the brackets)* I mean that the `[` and `]` inside the outer `[...]` are ignored by the Java regex engine.

Comment: Very clear now. Thank you. But i can only accept answer after 5 minutes.

Comment: @Rajkishan does your output can have this KH100 ?

Comment: @raghavendra: it should not as OP need to *match a string can be either KH1 or KH2 or ... KH99*.

Comment: @raghavendra : nope, there is no name like KH100. These are actually device names that can be KH1 to KH99.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I did not even look at other answer since I was typing.

Comment: @stribizhev : If i want to ignore case? Do i have to write another match for `[k][h][1-9][0-9]?` Can i do it in a single match?

Comment: That is why I kept a variant with `[K][H]`. You can add the lowercase letters there: `[Kk][Hh]`. OR, you can use the internal modifier `(?i)` to make the whole pattern case-insensitive: `"(?i)kh[1-9][0-9]?"`.

Comment: Note that this also matches `"xyzKH99xyz"`. If this is not okay, you should add `^` and `$`: `name.matches("^[kK][hH][1-9]\\d?$")`...

Comment: @FooF: Since the regex is used in the `matches` method, no anchors are necessary. This is Java.

Comment: @stribizhev weird, but seems true per my testing (it is ten years since I last time programmed in Java). It is off topic, but I am wondering why there is "^" and "$" mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?

Comment: @FooF: You need them if you plan to use the regex with `Matcher.find()`, or `replaceAll()`, or `split()`....

Answer (score 4):

First of all those outer square brackets are incorrect. Remove them. Second of all, your regular expression can be simplified *a lot*. You do not need two separate expressions, nor do you need to enclose the single characters `K` and `H` in a character class. Try:

```
KH[1-9][0-9]?
```

This will match the literal characters `KH`, followed by a digit 1 through 9, and optionally another digit 0 through 9 - illustrated by the following legal strings:

```
KH1
KH2
...
KH8
KH9
KH10
KH11
...
KH18
KH19
KH20
KH21
...
KH98
KH99
```

Comment: i am have some confusion with the question can we try like this KH\d+

Comment: @raghavendra I think no. We can't as OP has already defined that he wants the integer value starting from 1 and upto 99 only

Comment: @NarendraSisodia ok understood thank you i think like those are only inputs

Comment: Nope you can't check `KH1 or KH2 or ... KH99`

Comment: for KH100  the above regex is failing

Comment: Yes its because they have constructed it for `1` to `99` only and not for `100`

Comment: @Ic for posting the exact solution at very first.. +1

Answer (score 3):

You may use single regex.

```
if(name.matches("KH(?:[1-9]\\d|[1-9])")) {
```